# Why can't I connect with a non-browser application to this url?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Anyone knows why this url rejects connection requests being sent by a non-browser application (wget,curl, elinks!): http://sube.garanti.com.tr

https://sube.garanti.com.tr/isube/login/en

It's my bank account and I'm trying to make my transfers with a script but as you see this super secured servers do not allow me.

Any suggestions?

Azer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've tried doing this:

```
wget http://sube.garanti.com.tr
```

which timed-out.

but doing this:

```
wget https://sube.garanti.com.tr/isube/login/en
```

gave me website's source. It is frames base and I'm getting the frames definitions.

The reason for that is probably, that the site is inaccesible through normal (http) connection, you have to use secured one (https).

However, as a rule of thumb, I'd try to set User-Agent: header for any such application, as noted by pjc50.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
wget --referer="http://www.google.com" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6" --header="Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" --header="Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" --header="Keep-Alive: 300"
```

This may trick the site into thinking you have a "legitimate" browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you need to login before doing anything at this url?

You can login into sites by using perl's LWP, for example, by submitting login forms properly.

P.S. I can't connect to sube.garanti.com.tr with my browser either.

Comment: Yep, the two url you give let to nowhere for me too.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK wgte, curl opens the site in the server side. So check for your firwall (if any) and see if it is blocked.

Also the site can also be blocking incoming requests. Its a banking site and we can expect some security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites check the User-Agent: header. You might have to configure your downloader to identify itself as "Mozilla" rather than itself.